# filter overlapped rows in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this...

```
id  areaId  date        fromHour tohour
 1     485  31-08-2015  10       16
 2     485  31-08-2015  17       22
 3     485  31-08-2015  13       16
 4     460  31-08-2015  15       19
```

I used this query:

```
select t.* from tableName t
 join (select areaId, date,  count(*) as NumDuplicates
 from tableName group by areaId, date having NumDuplicates > 1 ) tsum
 on t.areaId = tsum.areaId and t.date = tsum.date
```

... from which I presently receive a result set like this ...

```
id areaId date       fromHour tohour
 1    485 31-08-2015 10       16
 2    485 31-08-2015 17       22
 3    485 31-08-2015 13       16
```

However, I would instead like to receive a result set like this...

```
id areaId date       fromHour tohour
 1    485 31-08-2015 10       16
 3    485 31-08-2015 13       16
```

I'm now going to explain the criteria by which rows 1 and 3 are selected, but rows 2 and 4 are not...

**Rows 1 and 3 are selected because:**
They have the same areaId and the same Date, then fromHour in row 3 is overlapped with the hour in rows 1.
fromhour 13 in row 3 is between fromHour 10 and toHour 16 in row 1

**Rows 2 and 4 are not selected because:**
Row 2 not overlapped hours with any other row it begins from 17 to 22 the others (row 1 and 3) are before this time.
Row 4 not in the same areaId even if it have the same date.

Here's a diagram:

```
id  areaId   08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 1     485          |-----------------|
 2     485                               |--------------|
 3     485                   |--------|
 4     460                         |-----------|
```

**Conclusion:**
I want to select the rows that have the same areaId and date, only if they have overlapped hours(fromHour : toHour).

Comment: SQL statements do not retrieve data from HTML tables.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused!!!

Comment: why are you saying that second row doesn't overlap with anything when it does, with last returned row?

Comment: I know it doesn't returns HTML, I'm new in stackoverflow editor and I was trying to make the view looks readable, but the editor is very confusing :)

Comment: Please edit your question to explain a) why rows 1 & 3, and b) why rows 2 & 4 are not.

Comment: I've done it now. I modified the row# 2. @Strawberry

Comment: I've rolled back. Now can you try editing the last line again.

Comment: where does 20 come from?

Comment: Done now finally. @Strawberry
 Thanks for your help.

Comment: make it 16 , Sorry I just want to explain the proplem, don't concentrate on the numbers, I will edit it now

Comment: The numbers would appear to be essential to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,area_id  INT NOT NULL NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
,from_hour INT NOT NULL
,to_hour INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1     ,485  ,'2015-08-31'  ,10      , 16),
(2     ,485  ,'2015-08-31'  ,17      , 22),
(3     ,485  ,'2015-08-31'  ,13      , 16),
(4     ,460  ,'2015-08-31'  ,15      , 19);

SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.area_id = x.area_id 
            AND y.date = x.date 
            AND y.from_hour < x.to_hour 
            AND y.to_hour > x.from_hour 
            AND y.id <> x.id;
+----+---------+------------+-----------+---------+
| id | area_id | date       | from_hour | to_hour |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+---------+
|  3 |     485 | 2015-08-31 |        13 |      16 |
|  1 |     485 | 2015-08-31 |        10 |      16 |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

Note that you should store dates using a date data type, and seriously consider storing `datetime_start, datetime_end` instead of `date, from_hour, to_hour`.

Comment: is it an answer to the question in some way?

Comment: Yeah that's worked for me, Thank you so much. @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not satisfied this approach is as efficient as it could be, but it may at least help the discussion. The specific approach I adopted requires a table of integers (i simply used 0 to 24 for that) which is used to determine which hours are "in common" across rows in this subquery:

```
select
    areaId, `date`, n.n
from tablename t
inner join tblNums n on n.n between t.fromHour and t.tohour
group by
    areaId, `date`, n.n
having count(*) > 1
;
```

The result (from the sample in the question) for that subquery is:

```
| areaId |                     date |  n |
|--------|--------------------------|----|
|    485 | August, 31 2015 00:00:00 | 13 |
|    485 | August, 31 2015 00:00:00 | 14 |
|    485 | August, 31 2015 00:00:00 | 15 |
|    485 | August, 31 2015 00:00:00 | 16 |
```

That result can be joined back to the source rows (and via distinct to avoid repetition) will list the rows that share an overlapping period

```
select distinct
     t.*
from tableName t
inner join (
        select
            areaId, `date`, n.n
        from tablename t
        inner join tblNums n on n.n between t.fromHour and t.tohour
        group by
            areaId, `date`, n.n
        having count(*) > 1
       ) o on t.areaId = o.areaId and t.date = o.date
           and t.fromHour = o.n or t.tohour = o.n
 ;

| id | areaId |                     date | fromHour | tohour |
|----|--------|--------------------------|----------|--------|
|  3 |    485 | August, 31 2015 00:00:00 |       13 |     16 |
|  1 |    485 | August, 31 2015 00:00:00 |       10 |     16 |
```

data:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName 
    (`id` int, `areaId` int, `date` datetime, `fromHour` int, `tohour` int)
;

INSERT INTO tableName 
    (`id`, `areaId`, `date`, `fromHour`, `tohour`)
VALUES
    (1, 485, '2015-08-31 00:00:00', 10, 16),
    (2, 485, '2015-08-31 00:00:00', 17, 22),
    (3, 485, '2015-08-31 00:00:00', 13, 16),
    (4, 460, '2015-08-31 00:00:00', 15, 19)
;


CREATE TABLE tblNums
    (`n` int)
;

INSERT INTO tblNums
    (`n`)
VALUES
    (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),
    (12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23), (24);
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30cd1/1

Answer (score 0):

The final query That I used to get what I want, Thanks to @Strawberry

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM my_table x 
JOIN my_table y 
ON y.area_id = x.area_id 
AND y.date = x.date 
AND y.from_hour <= x.to_hour 
AND y.to_hour >= x.from_hour 
AND y.id <> x.id;
```

I just added equal to greater than and less than, o avoid getting overlapped hours when to_hour and from_hour are equaled.
Thank you again. Hope this helps others.